# Prepare statement inside a loop

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I trying execute a query inside a loop.
I am tryning this code :

```
public List<Products> DisplayProducts(String []a)
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
      List<Products> Data=null;
    try
    {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
         String query = "select  * from products where Brand=?";
        PreparedStatement stmt=DataBaseConnection.DBConn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, a[i]);


        rs=stmt.executeQuery();
       }
       if(rs.next())
       {
           rs.beforeFirst();
          Data=new ArrayList<Products>();
       while(rs.next())
       {
           Products p=new Products();
           p.setTitle(rs.getString(2));
           p.setCategory(rs.getString(3));
           p.setSubCategory(rs.getString(4));
           p.setSubCategoryTwo(rs.getString(5));
           p.setPrice(rs.getInt(6));
           p.setFlavour(rs.getString(7));
           p.setImage(rs.getString(8));
           p.setBrand(rs.getString(9));
           p.setInstock(rs.getString(10));
           p.setInstockQty(rs.getInt(11));
           Data.add(p);

       }
       }
       return Data;

}
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have a jsp page where I have Checkboxes and I am displaying multiple products on this page. I am sorting this products by **BRANDS**.  User selects Brand by checking checkbox.

I am passing the value of checkbox to a servlet and on that servlet calling function Display Products:

```
String arr[]=request.getParameterValues("On");     
List<Products> Data=new SessionBeanClass().DisplayProducts(arr);
```

Please tell me how do I execute this and get the result ?

Comment: what is your problem? where error occurred? Please make question more clear.

Comment: Problem is i am returning a List when select query is executed but i am not getting anything in List

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to return the list of all products with the checkbox ticked. In that case i suppose you have a logic error here. This method only returns the last Product record.
Instead of looping through different id you could use 'IN' clause and return all at once.  There are many differet ways to achieve IN clause. The one given below is a simple alternative. You could check for various operations in http://www.journaldev.com/2521/jdbc-preparedstatement-in-clause-alternative-approaches or http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

In addition to that try following java naming conventions and clean up connections using finally

Try

```
public List<Products> DisplayProducts(String[] a) {
        ResultSet rs;
        List<Products> data;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        try {
            StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder();
            for(String str : a){
                param.append("'").append(str).append("', ");
            }
            String query = "select  * from products where Brand in (" + param.substring(0, param.length() - 2) + ")";
            stmt = DataBaseConnection.DBConn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs != null) {
                data = new ArrayList<Products>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Products p = new Products();
                    p.setTitle(rs.getString(2));
                    p.setCategory(rs.getString(3));
                    p.setSubCategory(rs.getString(4));
                    p.setSubCategoryTwo(rs.getString(5));
                    p.setPrice(rs.getInt(6));
                    p.setFlavour(rs.getString(7));
                    p.setImage(rs.getString(8));
                    p.setBrand(rs.getString(9));
                    p.setInstock(rs.getString(10));
                    p.setInstockQty(rs.getInt(11));
                    data.add(p);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            stmt.close();
        }
        return data;
}
```

**Explanation as per comment**

Ok. I suppose your idea here is to pass a set of brand names say adidas, nike, etc.. and select all the product details. So you need to do something like `select * from products where Brand in ('adidas', 'nike')`. This will give you all the products. So for this you pass the selected brand names as a string array. So what i did was to get the values from array and format it and make it as argument for IN clause. So of IN clause it needs comma separated values. Since its a Sting we need to give single quote `'` as well. So from an array `[adidas, nike]` i need to construct `'adidas', 'nike'`. That is what done in the for loop, appending ' and , (comma). So after for loop we'll have an additional comma and space at the end (e.g. 'adidas', 'nike', ). In order to remove this i remove the last two charaters by taking substring as `param.substring(0, param.length() - 2)`. This is fed to the query and retrieve the result.

Comment: If you're advising to properly close connections, why don't you add that to your example? It's not going to be much bigger with try-with-resources. Also, putting data inside the try would allow to reduce the scope and catch the mistake the OP made a lot easier (and also follows conventions)

Comment: @Ordous : I was just trying to give a quick example not a complete implementation. I have updated my answer anyway. Thank you.. :)

Comment: Come to think of it, the OP never actually closes neither connection nor statement/rs, which likely screws up any pooling mechanism. But you're right, that's not related to the logic issue at hand.

Comment: @Syam
Isn't there any way by which i can return the products of only selected brands by checkbook.
Why can't i execute the Prepare statement multiple times.

Comment: This piece of code does that. The input array should have the all the selected brand names and it returns all the products matching that brand name. You can definitely execute prepared statement multiple times. However each execution is actually a database call so its better to keep that traffic less for performance gain.

Comment: In your logic the for loop keeps on executing and overwriting the result set. So finally when you exit from the loop the resultSet will only have the last result. and you iterate over that to set product. That was the logical error.

Comment: @Syam May i know one can tell me how your logic is working you are passing param in query may i know please

Comment: Updated in the answer. Hope that helps.